# Need to use the graphqlHTTP function by importing it from graphql package but it is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

I changed the codes multiple times for this part but it still showing errors, I don't know where else I should change the code. Yes, I did tried the methods from the previous post about graphqlHttp is not a function but I'm still getting the errors

```sh
errors: C:\Users\justj\Documents\Web Project\MERN Stack
Projects\event-booking\app.js:35 app.use('/graphql', graphqlHttp({

TypeError: graphqlHttp is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\justj\Documents\Web Project\MERN Stack Projects\event-booking\app.js:35:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {graphqlHTTP} = require('express-graphql');

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: buildSchema(`
        type RootQuery {
            events: [String!]!

        }

        type RootMutation {
            createEvent(name: String): String 

        }

        schema {
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation 
        }
        
    `), 

    rootValue: {
        events: () => {
            return ['Cooking', 'Sailing', 'Coding']; 

        },
        createEvent: (args) => {
            const eventName = args.name; 
            return eventName; 

        }
    },
    graphiql: true 
    
    })
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Look this [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphql)

The right way to execute code:

‍‍‍‍‍‍

```
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;
```

require('express-graphql') returns an object with a property called graphqlHTTP that is the function you want to call.